# Multiple cell types in section of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am trying to aggregate data from three social networks (Facebook,LinkedIn,Twitter). I have all the appropriate and correct feeds and I also have difference cell types for them.

The question i want to ask is, how can i make a UITableView, containing 10 sections with 3 cells(plus three different cell types) per section in this order

Section 1:

[Facebook cell index 0 of the feed array]

[Twitter cell index 0 of the feed array]

[LinkedIn cell index 0 of the feed array]

Section 2:

[Facebook cell index 1 of the feed array]

[Twitter cell index 1 of the feed array]

[LinkedIn cell index 1 of the feed array]

Section 3:
etc etc etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     return 3;

 }

 -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
      return 10;
   }

 -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"cellId";
    customCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  if(indexPath.row == 0)
   {
        cell.textLabel.text = [FbFeed objectAtIndex:indexpath.section];

       // set FacebookCell
        cell


   }
  else if (indexPath.row == 1)
   {
    // set TwitterCell
    cell.textLabel.text = [tweetFeed objectAtIndex:indexpath.section];

   }
  else if (indexPath.row ==2)
  {
    cell.textLabel.text = [linkedinFeed objectAtIndex:indexpath.section];


    //set linkedin
  }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: This works good, but how should I increment my feed array? I mean, it gives me the same values for all sections, it doesn't increment the objects in the feed arrays.

Comment: It gives me the same index in the appropriate feed arrays all the time.

Comment: Works great! Thank you for the help, hope I can help you out someday :)

Comment: @user2282749 I am sure,someday you will help me out! :)

Answer (score 4):

Play with the table view's data source & delegate. What's important is to use 3 different cell identifiers for 3 types of cells (unless you want them to have same look).

```
-numberOfSectionsInTableView: {
    return 10;
}

–tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: {
    return 3;
}

-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FacebookCell"];

        if (cell == nil) {
             // Init FB cell here
        }

        // Load FB feed data into the cell here
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        // Twitter Cell, remember to user a different cell identifier
    }
    else ...
}
```

Comment: Much like the answer I got below, this works good, but the trouble is I need the values of the cells to increment in every section. What I am trying to say is, In the first section I want to have the objects at index 0 from all my feeds for all cells, in section 2 the objects at index 1 from all my feeds for all cells and so on..

Answer (score 3):

To build off the example, this can be used for any multiple type cells. You don't always have to use the row number to decide the type. You can get an object at the row and decide what type to show.

Also, if you are using storyboard, just add another prototype cell in the table, assign it a unique identifier, and set it up so you can use it. Works really well if you need different layouts that depend on the data returned.

```
-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    //Check what cell type it is. In this example, its using the row as the factor. You could easily get the object and decide from an object what type to use.
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Type1Cell"];

        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Type2Cell"];

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Type3Cell"];

        return cell;
    }
}
```